# Access Google Chrome history from incognito window

Tags: google-chrome, history, private-browsing

Back in the old days of Chrome, you could view `chrome://history` straight from an incognito window (it would automatically open a new non-incognito window to view history), but these days it displays a popup which tells you history isn't saved in incognito. Which obviously isn't what I'm wanting.

Any way to bring this back with an extension or something?

Comment: Why not open up the history in a standard window? That is after all where the history is created.

Comment: Did my answer help @jlaine3333?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to open history from incognito for some reason, you can for example:

- install [Better History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/egehpkpgpgooebopjihjmnpejnjafefi) extension
- go to `Extensions` -> `Manage Extensions` -> `Details` of Better History -> `Allow in Incognito` and turn that on
- pin the extension in non-incognito window

Now, whenever you'll click the pinned icon, it'll open history in a non-incognito window that supports saving history, either recently used one or a new one.